# What are the signature possibilities for multidimensional arrays with data objects?

Tags: php, oop, data-structures, multidimensional-array

A [recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322084/able-to-see-a-variable-in-print-rs-output-but-not-sure-how-to-access-it-in-co) gives an example of targeting a value in a nest of multidimensional arrays with data objects in a framework. The answer for this question turned out a long string of names connected with "->" operators similar to this (with actual named objects and arrays where here I use generic terms):

```
$object->object->object->array[index]->array['key']['key']->array['key']['key']
```

Unfortunately the post closed before I could post my clarifying question :( I've seen examples similar to this,

```
$object->($object->property)
```

...which uses parenthesis. Are there other syntax variations? What are the syntax restrictions to writing these statements in PHP?

Answer (score 3):

```
$object->($object->property)
```

Is not working PHP code. It will give syntax error. But probably you meant:

```
$object->{$object->property}
```

Which works like this:

```
$object->foo = 'bar';
$object->property = 'foo';

echo $object->property; # foo
echo $object->{$object->property}; # bar
```

It will first evaluate what's inside the parenthesis (`{$object->property}`) which is `foo` and then return `$object->foo` which is `bar`.