# Retrieving PHP value from array; array is starting at 2?

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mixed Array and object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725622/mixed-array-and-object)

I'm using `print_r` to see what the array contains:

```
Array ( 
    [2] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 2 
        [category] => 1 
        [sortorder] => 10001 
        [shortname] => 2323 
        [fullname] => asdaSDa 
        [startdate] => 1343188800 
        [visible] => 1 
        [groupmode] => 0 
        [groupmodeforce] => 0 
        [numsections] => 10 
        [role] => student 
        [rolename] => Student 
    ) 
)
```

I'd like to retrive the value of `[id]`. How can achieve this using PHP?

I've tried the following but receive an exception 500 from the server:

```
echo "<h1>CODIGO: ".$courses[2]["id"]."</h1>";
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: hmm shouldn't it be like `$courses[2]->id` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you have is an array of objects, so you can't access `id` with brackets . Instead, you need to use `->` to get the object property directly:

```
echo $array[2]->id;
```

If the key changes (but the element is the first), use [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/array_shift):

```
$first = array_shift( $array);
echo $first->id;
```

Similarly, use [`array_pop()`](http://php.net/array_pop) if the element is the last in the array.