# Parse xml array in php

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Able to see a variable in print_r()'s output, but not sure how to access it in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322084/able-to-see-a-variable-in-print-rs-output-but-not-sure-how-to-access-it-in-c)

```
SimpleXMLElement Object

(
[Header] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
    )

[Body] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [CreateUserResponse] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [username] => anup_165
                [password] => xnrrtgohgv
                [result] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [succeeded] => true
                        [errorCode] => 0
                        [errorText] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

i want to fetch username , password and succeeded from the above array

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
$username = (string) $xml->Body["CreateUserResponse"]->username;
$password = (string) $xml->Body["CreateUserResponse"]->password;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well i am going out on a limb here, but it might be something like:

```
$object['body']['CreateUserResponse']['username']
```

and
     $object['body']['CreateUserResponse']['password']

Answer (score 0):

```
    //For Parsing the xml 
    $xmltoaparse=simplexml_load_string($xmlresponse);


    foreach($xmltoaparse->children() as $iasorecord)
    {

             foreach($iasorecord as $iasouserrecord)  //for each for machhnia attributes
                   {
                        foreach($iasouserrecord as $iasousersrecord)  //for each for machhnia attributes
                            {

                echo $iasousersrecord->getName();
                echo    $iasousersrecord;


                            }
                   }
    }
```