# How can I echo inside this array of values?

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Able to see a variable in print_r()'s output, but not sure how to access it in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322084/able-to-see-a-variable-in-print-rs-output-but-not-sure-how-to-access-it-in-c)

```
$response = $amazonEcs->category('DVD')->responseGroup('Large')->search("Matrix Revolutions");
var_dump($response);
```

I was using var_dump($response) and now I want to know how can I get the values of Item from 0 to 9.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Insted of a picture ... why don't you paste the var_dump output ??

Comment: @Baba, that's the var_dump output

Comment: @SuiGo, you should not post a picture of your code. Just copy and paste the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Item` is nested inside a couple of objects. Assuming your outer object is `$response`, you are looking for:

```
$response->Items->Item[0]
```

`items` is an object `stdClass`, and `item` is a property of that object.  `item` itself is an array, having the keys `0-9` you are looking for.

Each of those array elements is then an object `stdClass` itself, so access its properties (which we can't see in your output) with the `->` operator.

```
$response->Items->Item[0]->someProperty
$response->Items->Item[9]->someOtherProperty
```

*Edit: Changed `item` to `Item`, as it is capitalized in the sample output.*

Comment: Can I echo $response->items->item[0]?

Comment: I triec echoing it it says "Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

Comment: @SuiGo Not directly, because `item[0]` is not a string. It's an object.  You can `var_dump($response->items->item[0]` to see what's inside it. It has its own additional properties (like `someProperty, someOtherProperty` in my example above) which you need to access.

Answer (score 1):

Use "->" to go inside objects and use [] to go inside arrays.

So, you are looking for

```
  $response->items->item
```

Use foreach to loop :

```
 foreach ($response->items->item as $item)
  {

            // Process $item, which will be $item[0], $item[1].. in each iteration.
   }
```