# How to get data from the WP_User Object inside a array

Tags: php, wordpress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Able to see a variable in print_r()'s output, but not sure how to access it in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322084/able-to-see-a-variable-in-print-rs-output-but-not-sure-how-to-access-it-in-c)

How do I pull the ID from the WP_User object inside this array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [lid] => WP_User Object
            (
                [data] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [ID] => 24
                        [user_login] => John Foo
                        [user_pass] => $P$BP0Qa4
                        [user_nicename] => john-foo
                        [user_email] => johnfoo@gmail.com
                        [user_url] => 
                        [user_registered] => 2012-10-10 11:16:24
                        [user_activation_key] => 
                        [user_status] => 0
                        [display_name] => John Foo
                    )

                [ID] => 24
                [caps] => Array
                    (
                        [commissie] => 1
                    )

                [cap_key] => sa_wp_capabilities
                [roles] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => commissie
                    )

                [allcaps] => Array
                    (
                        [edit_posts] => 1
                        [read] => 1
                        [level_1] => 1
                        [level_0] => 1
                        [delete_posts] => 1
                        [commissie] => 1
                    )

                [filter] => 
            )

        [lid_rol] => Voorzitter
    )
)
```

And I use the following code:

```
<?php 

$rows = get_field('commissie_lid');
if($rows)
{
    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
        $values = get_field('commissie_lid');
            if($values)
            {
                echo '<ul>'; 
                foreach($values as $value)
                {
                    foreach ($value['lid'] as $liddata) {
                        echo $liddata->ID;                  

                }

               // allways good to see exactly what you are working with
               echo '<pre>';
                   print_r($values);
               echo '</pre>';

            } 
            echo '</ul>';
        } 
    }

}

 ?>
```

It returns the user id, but also a lot of the following notices:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here: `foreach ($value['lid'] as $liddata) {`

At that point, `$value['lid']` is the `WP_User` object itself, so that foreach ends up iterating over all of the properties of the `WP_User` object.

If you eliminate that foreach, you should be able to directly access the public properties of the object from `$value['lid']` (e.g. `$value['lid']->ID`, or `$value['lid']->roles[0]`).

Hope that helps.