# stdClass Object values in variable php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

hi i am little stuck in one situation i want single value in $variable of user_email

```
WP_User Object ( [data] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 556853 [user_login] => vaknunispi@nedoz.com [user_pass] => $P$ButkcNwAZr4NSd4sPnoxwOd1G0hh0I/ [user_nicename] => vaknunispinedoz-com [user_email] => vaknunispi@nedoz.com [user_url] => [user_registered] => 2021-03-13 04:57:36 [user_activation_key] => 1615611730:$P$BGz9hvu5gNh8M7kTI/w7I4DnbzzTxP. [user_status] => 0 [display_name] => vaknunispi@nedoz.com ) [ID] => 556853 [caps] => Array ( [candidate] => 1 ) [cap_key] => jobo_capabilities [roles] => Array ( [0] => candidate ) [allcaps] => Array ( [read] => 1 [edit_posts] => [delete_posts] => [candidate] => 1 ) [filter] => [site_id:WP_User:private] => 1 )
```

here is the data i get i m little confused

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/12867832/1138192

Comment: isnt there any other solution without foreach?

Comment: no, you don't need foreach, just $var->data->user_email, it's an object wrapping inside WP_User object