# Extract values from php array

Tags: php, object, multidimensional-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Able to see a variable in print_r()'s output, but not sure how to access it in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322084/able-to-see-a-variable-in-print-rs-output-but-not-sure-how-to-access-it-in-c)

I am using SOAP to get data from the server and in response i am getting a php array like this

```
Array
(
 [BookResult] => stdClass Object
 (
  [PNR] => 5WPODU
  [BookingId] => 31149
  [Status] => stdClass Object
   (
    [StatusCode] => 03
    [Description] => Fare is not available at the time of booking
    [Category] => BK
   )
  [SSRDenied] => N
  [ProdType] => Flight
 )
)
```

All i want to know is how can i extract "PNR" and "StatusCode" value in separate variables so that i can store them in database.

Tried this not working

```
$p = (object) $array;
echo $p->StatusCode;
```

Comment: Try `$array["BookResult"]->PNR` for PNR and `$array["BookResult"]->Status->StatusCode` for StatusCode

Comment: u should get it as either json or xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var_dump($array['BookResult']->PNR);   
var_dump($array['BookResult']->Status->StatusCode);
```

Comment: Not Working- Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

`$PNR = $array["BookResult"]->PNR;

 $StatusCode= $array["BookResult"]->Status->StatusCode;`

$array is an array. So first dive is $array['BookResult'].
BookResult is stdClass instance so next goes $array['BookResult']->Status (get object's property).
Status is also stdClass instance so get it's property: $array['BookResult']->Status->StatusCode

Comment: Notice:
Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Must work if var_dump gives you exactly what you posted

Comment: WARNING! You must not do `(object) $array;` before trying to use code i've posted! No modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming results are being stored in $array

```
echo $array['BookResult']->Status->StatusCode;
echo $array['BookResult']->PNR;
```

Comment: Not Working-
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object