# How to out put the result?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Able to see a variable in print_r()'s output, but not sure how to access it in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322084/able-to-see-a-variable-in-print-rs-output-but-not-sure-how-to-access-it-in-c)

The output of `print_r($node)` is the following.

```
[field_pimage] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [fid] => 4
                            [alt] => 
                            [title] => 
                            [width] => 1440
                            [height] => 900
                            [uid] => 1
                            [filename] => 200801232112524201.jpg
                            [uri] => public://200801232112524201.jpg
                            [filemime] => image/jpeg
                            [filesize] => 122349
                            [status] => 1
                            [timestamp] => 1351403970
```

I want to output the `[uri]`'s value, how should I do it?

```
 $node->field_pimage->und->0->['uri'];  //but it doesn't work?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with arrays, not objects.

So you either need `$node->field_pimage['und'][0]['uri']` (if `$node` itself is an object) or `$node['field_pimage']['und'][0]['uri']` (if `$node` is an array, too)

Answer (score 1):

As it's an array... it should be accessed using...

```
$node['field_pimage']['und'][0]['uri'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $node["field_pimage"]["und"]["0"]["uri"];
```

Comment: I didn't down vote but - you need single quotes

Comment: you don't **need** single quotes, the performance gain from doing so would be negligible. Do whatever is more readable for yourself

Comment: Ah - I didn't realise there was a preformance gain, just makes it easier to read! I should have phrased it better sorry! ^^

Comment: I always write strings with double quotes if it's possible, this is usual for ppl who started with something like `VB`. And for performance it's impossibly negligible. So as @MLeFevre said `I do whatever is more readable for me` :)

Answer (score 0):

Since they are all arrays you can use this syntax;

```
$node['field_pimage']['und'][0]['uri'];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a multidimensional array.

Work down the hierarchy of the array.

```
$uri = $node['field_pimage']['und'][0]['uri'];

print($uri);
```