# php and session: how get an associative array from a session variable?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Able to see a variable in print_r()'s output, but not sure how to access it in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322084/able-to-see-a-variable-in-print-rs-output-but-not-sure-how-to-access-it-in-c)

I need to work on an existing website with a connected user:

```
<?php session_start();
print_r($_SESSION); ?>
```

This code outputs:

```
Array([%http_user%] => Array
    (
        [profile_id] => 72
        [username] => john
        [session_id] => 4ek79umrrpael7vvb4ls3diaq4
    )

[registration_invite_code] =>
```

)

That's what I need. It try to get "john" into my `$username` variable:

any idea how ?

I've tried with:

```
$_SESSION[0]

$_SESSION["%http_user%"]

$_SESSION->username
```

No way.

Any way how to retrieve this username ?

Thanks

Comment: Tried print_r on $_SESSION['%http_user%'], I think username is in that array e.g.$_SESSION['%http_user%']['username'] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$variable = $_SESSION['%http_user%']['username'];`