# Can I store an array in a variable?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Able to see a variable in print_r()'s output, but not sure how to access it in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322084/able-to-see-a-variable-in-print-rs-output-but-not-sure-how-to-access-it-in-c)

Can I store an array in a variable?

I have this array:

```
$_POST['product']
```

and when I print it:

```
echo "<PRE>";
print_r($_POST['product']);
echo "</PRE>";
```

the result is:

```
<PRE>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => cola
            [2] => wwww
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 2.00
            [5] => 0.00
            [6] => 2.00

        )

)
</PRE>
```

How can I store the value of the array in a variable? For example, I need to insert `[1] => cola` into the table in the database.

Comment: Can you just... make it clearer? Are you talking about `$_POST['product'][0][1]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the array like `$_POST['product'][0][1]` to get the value of cola.

For multiple inserting to database you should use foreach loop or for loop.

**UPDATED**

Alright,
Foreach Loop

```
foreach($_POST['product'] as $product) {
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO YOURTABLENAME('FIELD1','FIELD2'....) VALUES('".$product[0]."','".$product[1]."'....)"); 

}
```

I prefered to use for loop .

```
$count_array = count($_POST['product']);
for($i=0; $i>= $count_array; $i++){
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO YOURTABLENAME('FIELD1','FIELD2'....) VALUES('".$_POST['product'][$i]."','".$_POST['product'][$i]."'....)"); 
}
```

THere is also an optimize way for inserting in the database by avoiding the insert sql inside the for/foreach loop..
But for now that should work for you.. :)

Comment: *Remember to sanitize your inputs!!!1!11one* Use `mysql_real_escape_string()`, PDO, or some other method.

Answer (score 1):

You must use a foreach loop to "scan" the array and send an INSERT query to your database, like this :

```
<?php
$updateStmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES (:FIELD)");
foreach( $_POST['product'] as $key => $val ){
    $updateStmt->execute(array(
        ':FIELD' => $val
    ));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($_POST['product'])) {
    $colaVar = $_POST['product'][0][1];
    echo $colaVar; // outputs'cola'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that at all, just do the following:

```
$arr = $_POST['product']
echo $arr[0][1]
```

This is the normal way to access arrays values to do anything you want.

Comment: You don't need that at all, just do the following: `echo $_POST['product'][0][1]`

Comment: @AlvinWong Well you are more right but in the case of he does not want to process or change the value of the key!

Comment: but i insert multi array on one process what can i do ??

Comment: @Zamalkawyana looping through the array is the solution

Comment: @sємsєм how can through the array in loop ??

Comment: @Zamalkawyana use the following documentation http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: i try but i cannot solved it any one help me