# Parse json single array with php without foreach

Tags: php, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Able to see a variable in print_r()'s output, but not sure how to access it in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322084/able-to-see-a-variable-in-print-rs-output-but-not-sure-how-to-access-it-in-c)

PHP code to parse json:

```
<?php
$url = "http://xxx.com/request-url?type=json";
$string = file_get_contents($url);      
$json = json_decode($string);

if (count($json)) {
  echo $json->book->title;
} else {
  echo "No book found";
}
?>
```

Example json response:

```
{"book":[{"title":"Good day"}]}
```

Because of single array, i've removed foreach: foreach($json->book as $books)

I tried:
$json->book->title,
$json->title,
$json[book][title],
$json[title].

All not working.

Any help?

Comment: just tried, not working.

Comment: @richard: `print_r` is to show you how it is structured. You then *do* see how to access it. But better use `var_dump`, it gives more specific information. If nothing helps, you need to provide the [hexdump of the Json string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057572/how-can-i-get-a-hex-dump-of-a-string-in-php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do [`print_r($json)`](http://php.net/print_r) you get

```
stdClass Object
(
    [book] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [title] => Good day
                )

        )

)
```

You access StdClass properties with `->` and arrays with `[]`

So, obviously, it's

```
$json->book[0]->title;
```

[Click for Demo](http://codepad.org/TppnMqco)

If this is not working, then your JSON is likely invalid. Check it with http://www.jsonlint.com

Comment: Actually this does work. http://eval.in/5993