# How to access an array of arrays in PHP

Tags: php

I am working on Flight api. I am sending the request(From location,To location,From date..etc) and i am getting the response in the array format as below.

```
Array
(

        [AvailRequest] => Array
(
[Trip] => ONE
[Origin] => BLR
[Destination] => CMB
[DepartDate] => 2013-05-05
[ReturnDate] => 2013-05-10
[AdultPax] => 1
[ChildPax] => 0
[InfantPax] => 0
[Currency] => INR
[PreferredClass] => E
[Eticket] => true
[Clientid] => 
[Clienttype] => 
[PreferredAirline] => Array
(
)

)

[AvailResponse] => Array
(
[OriginDestinationOptions] => Array
(
[OriginDestinationOption] => Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[FareDetails] => Array
(
[ActualBaseFare] => 5250
[Tax] => 3980
[STax] => 0
[TCharge] => 0
[SCharge] => 0
[TDiscount] => 0
[TMarkup] => 0
[TPartnerCommission] => 0
[TSdiscount] => 0
[FareBreakup] => Array
(
[FareAry] => Array
(
[Fare] => Array
(
[PsgrType] => ADT
[BaseFare] => 5250
[Tax] => 3980
[TaxDataAry] => Array
(
[TaxData] => Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Country] => IN
        [Amt] => 00000260
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Country] => JN
        [Amt] => 00000412
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Country] => WO
        [Amt] => 00000225
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Country] => YQ
        [Amt] => 00002983
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [Country] => YR
        [Amt] => 00000100
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [Country] => Other
        [Amt] => 0
    )

)

)

)

)

)

[ocTax] => 0
)

[onward] => Array
(
[FlightSegments] => Array
(
[FlightSegment] => Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[AirEquipType] => 737
[ArrivalAirportCode] => MAA
[ArrivalAirportName] => CHENNAI
[ArrivalDateTime] => 2013-05-05T11:25:00
[DepartureAirportCode] => BLR
[DepartureAirportName] => BANGALORE
[DepartureDateTime] => 2013-05-05T10:25:00
[FlightNumber] => 2308
[MarketingAirlineCode] => 9W
[OperatingAirlineCode] => 9W
[OperatingAirlineName] => Jet Airways 
[OperatingAirlineFlightNumber] => 2308
[NumStops] => 0
[LinkSellAgrmnt] => SS
[Conx] => Y
[AirpChg] => N
[InsideAvailOption] => N
[GenTrafRestriction] => ?
[DaysOperates] => YNNNNNN
[JrnyTm] => 570
[EndDt] => 20130505
[StartTerminal] => ?
[EndTerminal] => D
[FltTm] => 60
[LSAInd] => Y
[Mile] => 168
[BookingClass] => Array
(
[Availability] => 007
[BIC] => T
)

[BookingClassFare] => Array
(
[bookingclass] => T
[classType] => Economy
[farebasiscode] => Z4zAhRL7boXLdF8E7pg/Gg==
[Rule] => Cancellation Penalty: All bookings done are subject to the cancellation penalty levied by the respective airline.
In addition to the airline's cancellation penalty, we charge a service fee of Rs. 200 per passenger for all cancellations.|Date Change Penalty: In addition to the airline's date change penalty, we charge a service fee of Rs. 250 per passenger for any date changes.|
)

)

[1] => Array
(
[AirEquipType] => 737
[ArrivalAirportCode] => CMB
[ArrivalAirportName] => Colombo
[ArrivalDateTime] => 2013-05-05T19:55:00
[DepartureAirportCode] => MAA
[DepartureAirportName] => CHENNAI
[DepartureDateTime] => 2013-05-05T18:30:00
[FlightNumber] => 252
[MarketingAirlineCode] => 9W
[OperatingAirlineCode] => 9W
[OperatingAirlineName] => Jet Airways 
[OperatingAirlineFlightNumber] => 252
[NumStops] => 0
[LinkSellAgrmnt] => SS
[Conx] => N
[AirpChg] => N
[InsideAvailOption] => N
[GenTrafRestriction] => ?
[DaysOperates] => YNNNNNN
[JrnyTm] => 570
[EndDt] => 20130505
[StartTerminal] => I
[EndTerminal] => ?
[FltTm] => 85
[LSAInd] => Y
[Mile] => 402
[BookingClass] => Array
(
[Availability] => 007
[BIC] => Q
)

[BookingClassFare] => Array
(
[bookingclass] => Q
[classType] => Economy
[farebasiscode] => Z4zAhRL7boXLdF8E7pg/Gg==
[Rule] => Cancellation Penalty: All bookings done are subject to the cancellation penalty levied by the respective airline.
In addition to the airline's cancellation penalty, we charge a service fee of Rs. 200 per passenger for all cancellations.|Date Change Penalty: In addition to the airline's date change penalty, we charge a service fee of Rs. 250 per passenger for any date changes.|
)

)

)

)

)

[Return] => Array
(
)

[id] => arzoo20
[key] => jT9o8XSks4Bf68R2DgKcVEb0gG2ZuxB2y+DauYeSiF3QweTiPhdGIWgoifR/a2Cj7pCpm05L2QnD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)

[1] => Array
(
[FareDetails] => Array
(
[ActualBaseFare] => 5250
[Tax] => 3980
[STax] => 0
[TCharge] => 0
[SCharge] => 0
[TDiscount] => 0
[TMarkup] => 0
[TPartnerCommission] => 0
[TSdiscount] => 0
[FareBreakup] => Array
(
[FareAry] => Array
(
[Fare] => Array
(
[PsgrType] => ADT
[BaseFare] => 5250
[Tax] => 3980
[TaxDataAry] => Array
(
[TaxData] => Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Country] => IN
        [Amt] => 00000260
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Country] => JN
        [Amt] => 00000412
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Country] => WO
        [Amt] => 00000225
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Country] => YQ
        [Amt] => 00002983
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [Country] => YR
        [Amt] => 00000100
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [Country] => Other
        [Amt] => 0
    )

)

)

)

)

)

[ocTax] => 0
)

[onward] => Array
(
[FlightSegments] => Array
(
[FlightSegment] => Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[AirEquipType] => AT7
[ArrivalAirportCode] => MAA
[ArrivalAirportName] => CHENNAI
[ArrivalDateTime] => 2013-05-05T23:25:00
[DepartureAirportCode] => BLR
[DepartureAirportName] => BANGALORE
[DepartureDateTime] => 2013-05-05T22:15:00
[FlightNumber] => 2736
[MarketingAirlineCode] => 9W
[OperatingAirlineCode] => 9W
[OperatingAirlineName] => Jet Airways 
[OperatingAirlineFlightNumber] => 2736
[NumStops] => 0
[LinkSellAgrmnt] => SS
[Conx] => Y
[AirpChg] => N
[InsideAvailOption] => N
[GenTrafRestriction] => ?
[DaysOperates] => YNNNNNN
[JrnyTm] => 1300
[EndDt] => 20130505
[StartTerminal] => ?
[EndTerminal] => D
[FltTm] => 70
[LSAInd] => Y
[Mile] => 168
[BookingClass] => Array
(
[Availability] => 007
[BIC] => T
)

[BookingClassFare] => Array
(
[bookingclass] => T
[classType] => Economy
[farebasiscode] => Z4zAhRL7boXLdF8E7pg/Gg==
[Rule] => Cancellation Penalty: All bookings done are subject to the cancellation penalty levied by the respective airline.
In addition to the airline's cancellation penalty, we charge a service fee of Rs. 200 per passenger for all cancellations.|Date Change Penalty: In addition to the airline's date change penalty, we charge a service fee of Rs. 250 per passenger for any date changes.|
)

)

[1] => Array
(
[AirEquipType] => 737
[ArrivalAirportCode] => CMB
[ArrivalAirportName] => Colombo
[ArrivalDateTime] => 2013-05-06T19:55:00
[DepartureAirportCode] => MAA
[DepartureAirportName] => CHENNAI
[DepartureDateTime] => 2013-05-06T18:30:00
[FlightNumber] => 252
[MarketingAirlineCode] => 9W
[OperatingAirlineCode] => 9W
[OperatingAirlineName] => Jet Airways 
[OperatingAirlineFlightNumber] => 252
[NumStops] => 0
[LinkSellAgrmnt] => SS
[Conx] => N
[AirpChg] => N
[InsideAvailOption] => N
[GenTrafRestriction] => ?
[DaysOperates] => NYNNNNN
[JrnyTm] => 1300
[EndDt] => 20130506
[StartTerminal] => I
[EndTerminal] => ?
[FltTm] => 85
[LSAInd] => Y
[Mile] => 402
[BookingClass] => Array
(
[Availability] => 007
[BIC] => Q
)

[BookingClassFare] => Array
(
[bookingclass] => Q
[classType] => Economy
[farebasiscode] => Z4zAhRL7boXLdF8E7pg/Gg==
[Rule] => Cancellation Penalty: All bookings done are subject to the cancellation penalty levied by the respective airline.
In addition to the airline's cancellation penalty, we charge a service fee of Rs. 200 per passenger for all cancellations.|Date Change Penalty: In addition to the airline's date change penalty, we charge a service fee of Rs. 250 per passenger for any date changes.|
)

)

)

)

)

[Return] => Array
(
)

[id] => arzoo21
[key] => LGqyrlHGfTRf68R2DgKcVEb0gG2ZuxB2y+DauYeSiF3QweTiPhdGIWgoifR/a2Cj7pCpm05L2QnD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)

[2] => Array
(
[FareDetails] => Array
(
[ActualBaseFare] => 5250
[Tax] => 3980
[STax] => 0
[TCharge] => 0
[SCharge] => 0
[TDiscount] => 0
[TMarkup] => 0
[TPartnerCommission] => 0
[TSdiscount] => 0
[FareBreakup] => Array
(
[FareAry] => Array
(
[Fare] => Array
(
[PsgrType] => ADT
[BaseFare] => 5250
[Tax] => 3980
[TaxDataAry] => Array
(
[TaxData] => Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Country] => IN
        [Amt] => 00000260
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Country] => JN
        [Amt] => 00000412
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Country] => WO
        [Amt] => 00000225
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Country] => YQ
        [Amt] => 00002983
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [Country] => YR
        [Amt] => 00000100
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [Country] => Other
        [Amt] => 0
    )

)

)

)

)

)

[ocTax] => 0
)

[onward] => Array
(
[FlightSegments] => Array
(
[FlightSegment] => Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[AirEquipType] => 739
[ArrivalAirportCode] => MAA
[ArrivalAirportName] => CHENNAI
[ArrivalDateTime] => 2013-05-05T07:40:00
[DepartureAirportCode] => BLR
[DepartureAirportName] => BANGALORE
[DepartureDateTime] => 2013-05-05T06:50:00
[FlightNumber] => 7029
[MarketingAirlineCode] => 9W
[OperatingAirlineCode] => 9W
[OperatingAirlineName] => Jet Airways 
[OperatingAirlineFlightNumber] => 7029
[NumStops] => 0
[LinkSellAgrmnt] => SS
[Conx] => Y
[AirpChg] => N
[InsideAvailOption] => N
[GenTrafRestriction] => ?
[DaysOperates] => YNNNNNN
[JrnyTm] => 785
[EndDt] => 20130505
[StartTerminal] => ?
[EndTerminal] => D
[FltTm] => 50
[LSAInd] => Y
[Mile] => 168
[BookingClass] => Array
(
[Availability] => 007
[BIC] => T
)

[BookingClassFare] => Array
(
[bookingclass] => T
[classType] => Economy
[farebasiscode] => Z4zAhRL7boXLdF8E7pg/Gg==
[Rule] => Cancellation Penalty: All bookings done are subject to the cancellation penalty levied by the respective airline.
In addition to the airline's cancellation penalty, we charge a service fee of Rs. 200 per passenger for all cancellations.|Date Change Penalty: In addition to the airline's date change penalty, we charge a service fee of Rs. 250 per passenger for any date changes.|
)

)

[1] => Array
(
[AirEquipType] => 737
[ArrivalAirportCode] => CMB
[ArrivalAirportName] => Colombo
[ArrivalDateTime] => 2013-05-05T19:55:00
[DepartureAirportCode] => MAA
[DepartureAirportName] => CHENNAI
[DepartureDateTime] => 2013-05-05T18:30:00
[FlightNumber] => 252
[MarketingAirlineCode] => 9W
[OperatingAirlineCode] => 9W
[OperatingAirlineName] => Jet Airways 
[OperatingAirlineFlightNumber] => 252
[NumStops] => 0
[LinkSellAgrmnt] => SS
[Conx] => N
[AirpChg] => N
[InsideAvailOption] => N
[GenTrafRestriction] => ?
[DaysOperates] => YNNNNNN
[JrnyTm] => 785
[EndDt] => 20130505
[StartTerminal] => I
[EndTerminal] => ?
[FltTm] => 85
[LSAInd] => Y
[Mile] => 402
[BookingClass] => Array
(
[Availability] => 007
[BIC] => Q
)

[BookingClassFare] => Array
(
[bookingclass] => Q
[classType] => Economy
[farebasiscode] => Z4zAhRL7boXLdF8E7pg/Gg==
[Rule] => Cancellation Penalty: All bookings done are subject to the cancellation penalty levied by the respective airline.
In addition to the airline's cancellation penalty, we charge a service fee of Rs. 200 per passenger for all cancellations.|Date Change Penalty: In addition to the airline's date change penalty, we charge a service fee of Rs. 250 per passenger for any date changes.|
)

)

)

)

)

[Return] => Array
(
)

[id] => arzoo22
[key] => DsEEIVONfp1f68R2DgKcVEb0gG2ZuxB2y+DauYeSiF3QweTiPhdGIWgoifR/a2Cj7pCpm05L2QnD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)
)

                )

        )

)
```

Now how to access this array of arrays. I want to display the result as below

```
Flight 1:

orign-destination: BLR-MAA-CMB 
Dep time : 2013-05-05T10:25:00
Arr time : 2013-05-05T19:55:00
Total Fare : 10,000

Flight 2:

orign-destination: BLR-MAA-CMB 
Dep time : 2013-05-05T10:25:00
Arr time : 2013-05-05T19:55:00
Total Fare : 10,000

Flight 3:

orign-destination: BLR-MAA-CMB 
Dep time : 2013-05-05T10:25:00
Arr time : 2013-05-05T19:55:00
Total Fare : 10,000
```

I dont know how to do that. Can any one help me in this.

Thanks in advance,
Shoba

Comment: possible duplicate of [Able to see a variable in print\_r()'s output, but not sure how to access it in code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322084/able-to-see-a-variable-in-print-rs-output-but-not-sure-how-to-access-it-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Ok First let me show you how to do this using a simple example

```
    $myArray = array();
    $myArray[] = array('name'=>'Russell');
    $myArray[] = array('name'=>'Sam')
    foreach($myArray as $list)
    {
    print $list['name'];
    }
```

you can see what this example shows is it will loop through each array and get the name.

Now lets do a sub array in an array

```
    $myArray = array();
    $myArray[] = array('name'=>'Russell', 'about_me'=>array('age'=>22));
    $myArray[] = array('name'=>'Sam', 'about_me'=>array('age'=>32))
    foreach($myArray as $list)
    {
    print $list['name'];
    }

    foreach($myArray as $list)
    {
    print $list['name'];
print $list['about_me']['age']; <-- this will print about the age of the person.
    }
```

Comment: `array('name'=>'Russell', 'name'=>'Sam')` is an array of strings, not an array of arrays. And because the key appears twice, this array really has just one element.

Comment: @Arjan sorry fixed my example

Comment: hi Russell i tried your example and implemented in my code as below to display all the flight numbers of 1st result as i given in the question. 

`$s=0;
foreach($array_data as $array)
{
echo $array['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption']['0']['onward']['FlightSegments']['FlightSegment']['$s']['FlightNumber'];
$s++;
}`

 but i am not getting any result. Please go through my question and check that i am ding correct or not.

Comment: I notice you have $s in your comment above, this means you will need to run another foreach inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to loop inside your array, level by level, and peint all relevant data you need. You can use [foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/it/control-structures.foreach.php) function to achieve this, please check documentation.

Answer (score 0):

First print your array:

```
print_r($yourarrayname);
```

Then print:

```
print_r($yourarrayname['AvailRequest']);
```

Then print:

```
print_r($yourarrayname['AvailRequest']['Trip']);
```

Then you will understand what I mean.