# how to print multiple array in joomla

Tags: php, arrays, joomla2.5

This is the cart array in the Virtuemart 2.0.22a ..
this is stored in "$cart"
how to print `[virtuemart_product_id] =&gt; 21` at 4.

```
 $cart=
           VirtueMartCart Object
(
    [products] =&gt; Array
        (
            [21] =&gt; stdClass Object
                (
                    [virtuemart_manufacturer_id] =&gt; Array
                        (
                        )

                    [slug] =&gt; stylish-shirt
                    [published] =&gt; 1
                    [virtuemart_product_price] =&gt; 
                    [virtuemart_product_id] =&gt; 21
                    [virtuemart_shoppergroup_id] =&gt; 
                    [product_price] =&gt; 450.00000
                    [override] =&gt; 0
                    [product_override_price] =&gt; 0.00000
                    [product_tax_id] =&gt; -1
                    [product_discount_id] =&gt; -1
                    [product_currency] =&gt; 68
                    [virtuemart_vendor_id] =&gt; 1
                    [product_parent_id] =&gt; 0
                    [product_sku] =&gt; 
                    [product_name] =&gt; Stylish Shirt
                    [product_s_desc] =&gt; 
                    [product_weight] =&gt; 
                    [product_weight_uom] =&gt; KG
                    [product_length] =&gt; 
                    [product_width] =&gt; 
                    [product_height] =&gt; 
                    [product_lwh_uom] =&gt; M
                    [product_in_stock] =&gt; 0
                    [product_ordered] =&gt; 0
                    [product_sales] =&gt; 0
                    [product_unit] =&gt; KG
                    [product_packaging] =&gt; 
                    [min_order_level] =&gt; 
                    [max_order_level] =&gt; 
                    [virtuemart_media_id] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [0] =&gt; 21
                        )

                    [step_order_level] =&gt; 
                    [image] =&gt; VmImage Object
                        (
                            [media_attributes] =&gt; 0
                            [setRole] =&gt; 
                            [file_name] =&gt; 3
                            [file_extension] =&gt; jpg
                            [virtuemart_media_id] =&gt; 21
                            [_foldersToTest:VmMediaHandler:private] =&gt; Array
                                (
                                    [0] =&gt; E:\wamp\www\ecomm\images\stories\virtuemart\product\
                                    [1] =&gt; E:\wamp\www\ecomm\images\stories\virtuemart\product\resized\
                                )

                            [_actions:VmMediaHandler:private] =&gt; Array
                                (
                                )

                            [_mLocation:VmMediaHandler:private] =&gt; Array
                                (
                                )

                            [_hidden:VmMediaHandler:private] =&gt; Array
                                (
                                )

                            [theme_url] =&gt; http://localhost/ecomm/components/com_virtuemart/
                            [virtuemart_vendor_id] =&gt; 1
                            [file_title] =&gt; 3.jpg
                            [file_description] =&gt; 
                            [file_meta] =&gt; 
                            [file_mimetype] =&gt; image/jpeg
                            [file_type] =&gt; product
                            [file_url] =&gt; images/stories/virtuemart/product/3.jpg
                            [file_url_thumb] =&gt; images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/3_90x90.jpg
                            [published] =&gt; 1
                            [file_is_downloadable] =&gt; 0
                            [file_is_forSale] =&gt; 0
                            [file_is_product_image] =&gt; 0
                            [shared] =&gt; 0
                            [file_params] =&gt; 
                            [file_lang] =&gt; 
                            [_translatable] =&gt; 
                            [_tablePreFix] =&gt; 
                            [created_on] =&gt; 2013-08-12 12:32:19
                            [created_by] =&gt; 572
                            [modified_on] =&gt; 2013-08-12 12:38:50
                            [modified_by] =&gt; 572
                            [file_url_folder] =&gt; images/stories/virtuemart/product/
                            [file_path_folder] =&gt; images\stories\virtuemart\product\
                            [file_url_folder_thumb] =&gt; images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/
                            [media_role] =&gt; file_is_displayable
                            [file_name_thumb] =&gt; 3_90x90
                        )

                    [categories] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [0] =&gt; 6
                        )

                    [virtuemart_category_id] =&gt; 6
                    [category_name] =&gt; Shirts
                    [link] =&gt; /ecomm/index.php/component/virtuemart/shirts/stylish-shirt-detail?Itemid=0
                    [packaging] =&gt; 
                    [quantity] =&gt; 1
                )

        )

    [_inCheckOut] =&gt; 
    [_dataValidated] =&gt; 
    [_blockConfirm] =&gt; 
    [_confirmDone] =&gt; 
    [_redirect] =&gt; 
    [_redirect_disabled] =&gt; 
    [_lastError] =&gt; 
    [vendorId] =&gt; 1
    [lastVisitedCategoryId] =&gt; 0
    [virtuemart_shipmentmethod_id] =&gt; 0
    [virtuemart_paymentmethod_id] =&gt; 1
    [automaticSelectedShipment] =&gt; 1
    [automaticSelectedPayment] =&gt; 1
    [BT] =&gt; 0
    [ST] =&gt; 0
    [tosAccepted] =&gt; 
    [customer_comment] =&gt; 
    [couponCode] =&gt; 
    [order_language] =&gt; 
    [cartData] =&gt; Array
        (
            [VatTax] =&gt; Array
                (
                )

            [duty] =&gt; 1
            [payment] =&gt; 0
            [paymentName] =&gt;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Able to see a variable in print\_r()'s output, but not sure how to access it in code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322084/able-to-see-a-variable-in-print-rs-output-but-not-sure-how-to-access-it-in-c)

Comment: What is your concrete question? Why for example isn't this documented? Should it normally not be accessed for example?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the output.. after lot of struggles

```
foreach($cart->products as $cur)
{
    echo $cur->virtuemart_product_id;
}
```