# Display particular field from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am working arround array in php

```
my array

 Array
 (
   [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [fieldId] => 2148632ds4134
        [content] => 20
    )

 )
```

I want display only [content] value i.e. 20 from above array.

Does anyone know how to do this ?

please help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Able to see a variable in print\_r()'s output, but not sure how to access it in code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322084/able-to-see-a-variable-in-print-rs-output-but-not-sure-how-to-access-it-in-c)

Comment: I bet that is not your concrete programming question. You should better describe what in concrete you'd like to know. Also take care when using `print_r`, it does not show the correct keys/properties all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Try like

```
echo $my_arr[0]->content;
```

Comment: It probably would be a bit too much now asking "Oh PHP has objects?", right? :) I was just fooling around a bit.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this. I assume your array variable is `$your_array`

```
echo $your_array[0]->content;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump($my_array->content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this function to your database abstraction layer class:

```
function fetchColumn($index) {
    array_map(create_function('$a', 'return $a["'.$index.'"];'),
        $this->fetchAll());
}
```

Then you use it like, `$data = $MyApp->dbo->fetchColumn("content");`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
echo $custome_array[0]->content;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
print_r($my_array->content);
```