# How to create an array from simple string?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [json decode in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270016/json-decode-in-php)

**I want to get my id in php, actually without that php sdk files.
So i am using this.**

```
$a = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/100004304380055...');
echo $a['id'];
```

The contents of the response are

```
{
    "id": "100004304380055",
    "name": "Ayush Mishra"
}
```

But it does not returns my `id 100004304380055`. I thing `$a` is not an array. I want to know how to make `$a` an array and then get my id by `$a['id']`. Please provide the code. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Nowhere are you parsing the data you get back.

Comment: Thanks Mario, But i have no idea of What is a Json string. :(

Answer (score 2):

The endpoint is returning a JSON string; which is a format used to convey object information as a string. Convert the string back to an object, and grab the `id` property:

```
$data = json_decode($response);
echo $data->id;
```

Where `$response` is the result of your call to `file_get_contents()`.