# php-how to parse single json array of objects

Tags: php, json, parsing

```
[{"CUSTOMERCODE":"9879","CUSTNAME":"ASHIQUE","MOBILE":"","NATION":"INDIA","AREA":"AL QUOZ"},{"CUSTOMERCODE":"5678","CUSTNAME":"SALIH","MOBILE":"971528381946","NATION":"UAE","AREA":"DEIRA"},{"CUSTOMERCODE":"2345","CUSTNAME":"HABEEB","MOBILE":"12345678","NATION":"SAUDI","AREA":"AL QOUZ 4"},{"CUSTOMERCODE":"5433","CUSTNAME":"AZHAR","MOBILE":"12345678","NATION":"USA","AREA":"AL QOUZ 3"},{"CUSTOMERCODE":"5698","CUSTNAME":"BAIJU","MOBILE":"12345678","NATION":"UK","AREA":"AL KHAIL"},{"CUSTOMERCODE":"3854","CUSTNAME":"RAHUL","MOBILE":"12345678","NATION":"KUWAIT","AREA":"AL QUOZ"},{"CUSTOMERCODE":"5623","CUSTNAME":"LINESH","MOBILE":"12345678","NATION":"UAE","AREA":"AL KHAIL"},{"CUSTOMERCODE":"9879","CUSTNAME":"ASHIQUE","MOBILE":"12345678","NATION":"INDIA","AREA":"AL QUOZ"},{"CUSTOMERCODE":"5678","CUSTNAME":"SALIH","MOBILE":"12345678","NATION":"UAE","AREA":"DEIRA"},{"CUSTOMERCODE":"2345","CUSTNAME":"HABEEB","MOBILE":"12345678","NATION":"SAUDI","AREA":"AL QOUZ 4"},{"CUSTOMERCODE":"5433","CUSTNAME":"AZHAR","MOBILE":"12345678","NATION":"USA","AREA":"AL QOUZ 3"},{"CUSTOMERCODE":"5698","CUSTNAME":"BAIJU","MOBILE":"12345678","NATION":"UK","AREA":"AL KHAIL"},{"CUSTOMERCODE":"3854","CUSTNAME":"RAHUL","MOBILE":"971557557863","NATION":"KUWAIT","AREA":"AL QUOZ"},{"CUSTOMERCODE":"5623","CUSTNAME":"LINESH","MOBILE":"12345678","NATION":"UAE","AREA":"AL KHAIL"}]
```

How can print each CUSTNAME in a loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [json decode in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270016/json-decode-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have json_decode result returning  a proper associative array

```
$myJson = json_decode($json, true);
```

do the fact you have an array of elements you could iterate over the array  and eg: using echo for show the value

```
foreach ($myJson as $key => $value){
      echo $value['CUSTNAME'] . '<br>';
}
```

and if  want use  a for loop

```
$cnt = count($myJson);

for ($i = 0; $i<$cnt; $i++){
    echo $myJson[$i]['CUSTNAME'] . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) json and use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) method to get each `CUSTNAME` key value.

```
$json = '[{"CUSTOMERCODE":"9879","CUSTNAME":"ASHIQUE","MOBILE":"","NATION":"INDIA","AREA":"AL QUOZ"},{"CUSTOMERCODE":"5678","CUSTNAME":"SALIH","MOBILE":"971528381946","NATION":"UAE","AREA":"DEIRA"},{"CUSTOMERCODE":"2345","CUSTNAME":"HABEEB","MOBILE":"12345678","NATION":"SAUDI","AREA":"AL QOUZ 4"},{"CUSTOMERCODE":"5433","CUSTNAME":"AZHAR","MOBILE":"12345678","NATION":"USA","AREA":"AL QOUZ 3"},{"CUSTOMERCODE":"5698","CUSTNAME":"BAIJU","MOBILE":"12345678","NATION":"UK","AREA":"AL KHAIL"},{"CUSTOMERCODE":"3854","CUSTNAME":"RAHUL","MOBILE":"12345678","NATION":"KUWAIT","AREA":"AL QUOZ"},{"CUSTOMERCODE":"5623","CUSTNAME":"LINESH","MOBILE":"12345678","NATION":"UAE","AREA":"AL KHAIL"},{"CUSTOMERCODE":"9879","CUSTNAME":"ASHIQUE","MOBILE":"12345678","NATION":"INDIA","AREA":"AL QUOZ"},{"CUSTOMERCODE":"5678","CUSTNAME":"SALIH","MOBILE":"12345678","NATION":"UAE","AREA":"DEIRA"},{"CUSTOMERCODE":"2345","CUSTNAME":"HABEEB","MOBILE":"12345678","NATION":"SAUDI","AREA":"AL QOUZ 4"},{"CUSTOMERCODE":"5433","CUSTNAME":"AZHAR","MOBILE":"12345678","NATION":"USA","AREA":"AL QOUZ 3"},{"CUSTOMERCODE":"5698","CUSTNAME":"BAIJU","MOBILE":"12345678","NATION":"UK","AREA":"AL KHAIL"},{"CUSTOMERCODE":"3854","CUSTNAME":"RAHUL","MOBILE":"971557557863","NATION":"KUWAIT","AREA":"AL QUOZ"},{"CUSTOMERCODE":"5623","CUSTNAME":"LINESH","MOBILE":"12345678","NATION":"UAE","AREA":"AL KHAIL"}]';

$data = json_decode($json);
echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_column($data, 'CUSTNAME'));
```